# Reading data from Azure Blob with Spark

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, spark-streaming

I am having issue in reading data from azure blobs via spark streaming

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://ip:8020/directory");
```

code like above works for HDFS, but is unable to read file from Azure blob

```
https://blobstorage.blob.core.windows.net/containerid/folder1/
```

Above is the path which is shown in azure UI, but this doesnt work, am i missing something, and how can we access it.

I know Eventhub are ideal choice for streaming data, but my current situation demands to use storage rather then queues

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to read data from blob storage, there are two things that need to be done. First, you need to tell Spark which native file system to use in the underlying Hadoop configuration. This means that you also need the [Hadoop-Azure JAR](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure/2.7.2) to be available on your classpath (note there maybe runtime requirements for more JARs related to the Hadoop family):

```
JavaSparkContext ct = new JavaSparkContext();
Configuration config = ct.hadoopConfiguration();
config.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem");
config.set("fs.azure.account.key.youraccount.blob.core.windows.net", "yourkey");
```

Now, call onto the file using the `wasb://` prefix (note the `[s]` is for optional secure connection):

```
ssc.textFileStream("wasb[s]://<BlobStorageContainerName>@<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>");
```

This goes without saying that you'll need to have proper permissions set from the location making the query to blob storage.

Comment: Thanks, i tried but i think some issue are still happening, is it possible to point a link to a working example

Comment: I don't have a working tutorial. What exception is occuring?

Comment: @duck Was it an internal dependency or something related to Hadoop? If so, tell us what it was so I can add it to the answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hi. Could you let me know about the different versions you are using?

Comment: @Madhukar What do you mean by *"different versions"*?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Versions of spark, Hadoop Azure Jar, Azure Storage jar etc. I am facing the same issue now.

Comment: I'm using Hadoop 2.7.2, but not using the Azure JAR. Have you had trouble with some versions?

Comment: I am working on the Datastax Spark with version 1.6.2. Hadoop version I think is 1.0.4. Any help here? @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: You could try the example listed in this blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/07/13/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally/

Comment: Not working: 
%%configure -f
{ "conf": {"org.apache.hadoop": "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.2" }}
then:
>JavaSparkContext ct = new JavaSparkContext();

Comment: Is it possible to access different storage accounts by setting the following entry config.set("fs.azure.account.key.youraccount.blob.core.windows.net", "yourkey"); in the hadoop configuration for each of those storage accounts?

Comment: @girip11 You'll be overriding with the same key, the config will only pick up the latest.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov How can I convert the javasparkcontext object to javastreamingcontext object? streamingcontext does not have hadoop configuration method.

Comment: This did solve some a few issues for me but now I get an error saying `Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Incorrect Blob type, please use the correct Blob type to access a blob on the server. Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual UNSPECIFIED.`. And I could find almost nothing for its resolution. FWIW, I am using Python SparkSession `spark.read.format("text").load(blob_folder)`. :(

Comment: you need to add it to spark.hadoop.fs.azure..... only fs.azure does not seem to work at least on my side

Answer (score 2):

As supplementary, there is a tutorial about HDFS-compatible Azure Blob storage with Hadoop which is very helpful, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage.

Meanwhile, there is an offical [sample](https://github.com/hdinsight/hdinsight-spark-examples) on GitHub for Spark streaming on Azure. Unfortunately, the sample is written for Scala, but I think it's still helpful for you.

Comment: I don't see anything related to reading from blob storage in the example. I've also read through the first link and there isn't anything there I see directly explaining how to provide a `NativeAzureFileSystem` to Spark. I think it would be good if you guys provide a concrete example of using blob storage as the underlying checkpoint directory for Spark.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The first link did help me better understand what these concepts are but it doesn't seem to talk much about how to use these features. Also, the second link doesn't work anymore.
Can you think of any reason which might lead me to `Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Incorrect Blob type, please use the correct Blob type to access a blob on the server. Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual UNSPECIFIED.`? I am using `Python` (`spark.read.format("text").load(blob_folder)`) but shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Apparently the `azure-storage-2.2.0.jar` did not support `APPEND_BLOB`. I upgraded to `azure-storage-4.0.0.jar` and it changed the error from `Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual UNSPECIFIED.` to `Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual APPEND_BLOB.`. Does anyone know how to pass the correct type to expect?

Answer (score -2):

df = spark.read.format(“csv”).load(“wasbs://blob_container@account_name.blob.core.windows.net/example.csv”, inferSchema = True)