# Connecting Blob to Spark failing

Tags: apache-spark, blob, azure-storage, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to connect spark coming in Hortonworks 2.4 distribution to Azure Blob storage and I was getting error "wasb filesystem not recognized " . I checked and many suggested downloading azure-sdk-for-java and creating package.

I am trying to create package using mvn but while running both mvn test and mvn package ; the process is getting hanged while testing. There is no error given , it just failed to return anything. I had changed testconfiguration.xml to reflect my blob account name. Below is the log files I am getting.

Is there something else that needs to be done to get jars ?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Microsoft Azure Storage Client SDK 4.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ azure-storage ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/adminhorton/kspark/azure-storage-java-master/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ azure-storage ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ azure-storage ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ azure-storage ---
[INFO] Compiling 52 source files to /home/adminhorton/kspark/azure-storage-java-master/target/test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test) @ azure-storage ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/adminhorton/kspark/azure-storage-java-master/target/surefire-reports
T E S T S

parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageAccountTests
Tests run: 33, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.057 sec
Running com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageUriTests
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.071 sec

com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageAccountTests.txt
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageUriTests.txt

com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageAccountTests.txt
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageUriTests.txt
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763472/reading-data-from-azure-blob-with-spark/37764434#37764434

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,  I am not sure you have configured your Storage Configuration rightly in your project. So I recommend you can follow these steps to check your configurations:

1.Create your Azure storage Account and set it in `core-site.xml` as this format:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.youraccount.blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>YOUR ACCESS KEY</value>
</property>
```

2.Restart the HDP service and use the `Hadoop fs –ls wasb://**.blob.core.windows.net/` to list the files in the container.

I strongly recommend you can refer to this blog [how-to-configure-hortonworks-hdp-to-access-azure-windows-storage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2015/09/01/how-to-configure-hortonworks-hdp-to-access-azure-windows-storage/) and official [document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-azure/index.html).

Meanwhile , @[Yuval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870803/yuval-itzchakov) provided the great sample about how to connect to Azure blob with Java SDK.