# NativeAzureFileSystem not recognizing other containers

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

My objective is to access, from spark-shell of an HD Insight instance, blobs that are located in a container inside the storage account over which the cluster was created.

These are the steps I took:

1. Created an HD Insight cluster over the container https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/**maincontainer**.
2. Created another container on the same storage account: https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/**extracontainer**.
3. Created a file named *person.json* inside the **extracontainer**: https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/extracontainer/data/person.json
4. Opened a spark-shell session

Then I executed the following code:

```
scala> import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

scala> val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml

scala> val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.newInstance(conf)
fs: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem = org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem@417e5282

scala> val files = fs.listFiles(new Path("wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data"), true)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Filewasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data does not exist.
```

Then I created the same folder and file on the **maincontainer**:
https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/maincontainer/data/person.json and I got the following result:

```
scala> val files = fs.listFiles(new Path("wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data"), true)
scala> while( files.hasNext() ) { println(files.next().getPath) }
wasb://maincontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/person.json
```

It shows me the file in the **maincontainer** and not the one in the **extracontainer**.

Does any one knows what's happening?

I also tried creating the FileSystem object using `new Configuration()` and I got the same behavior.

The correct behavior is obtained when using `hadoop fs` command line:

```
> hadoop fs -ls wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/
Found 1 item
-rwxrwxrwx   1        977 2017-02-27 08:46 wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/person.json
```

Comment: I found this useful and it's resolved my issue local after put hadoop-azure and azure-storage jar in install spark location in C:\Spark\jar\ in this folder

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to read data from Azure Blob Storage with Spark, but the `fs.defaultFS` setting for Hadoop Configuration was set for your `maincontainer` when you created the HDInsight instance.

There are two ways for implementing your needs.

1. Using the methods `addResource(new Path("wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data"))` or `set("fs.defaultFS", "wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data")` of class [`Configuration`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) to override the `fs.defaultFS` value for switching the resource reference, if the `fs.defaultFS` property in `core-site.xml` was not marked `<final>true</final>`. So first, you need to move to `/etc/hadoop/conf` to change it.
2. Refer to the similar SO thread [Reading data from Azure Blob with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763472/reading-data-from-azure-blob-with-spark/37782894), you can try to use the code below to read data.

   ```
   conf.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
   conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<youraccount>.blob.core.windows.net", "<yourkey>")
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @peter-pan-msft, the first and third solutions (`addResource` and `set("fs.azure", ...)`) didn't work. With the second solution I can see data from **extracontainer**, but I can't access data from **maincontainer**, which makes me conclude that the NativeAzureFileSystem can only see one container at a time (?). The following two commands however work fine: `hadoop fs -ls wasbs://extracontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data` and `hadoop fs -ls wasbs://maincontainer@mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/data`