# Deploying Spark code in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, apache-spark, bigdata

It is possible to deploy Spark code in Azure (Spark Cluster in Azure) without using HDInsight Spark?

Comment: Simply: Yes. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm fairly new to spark. Is there any link or steps where I can learn from? thanks!

Comment: http://spark.apache.org ... download it and configure it. Point your `core-site.xml` Hadoop XML file at Azure's file storage.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763472/reading-data-from-azure-blob-with-spark