# Provide blob type to read an Azure append blob from PySpark

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage

The ultimate goal is to able to read the data in my Azure container into a PySpark dataframe.

### Steps until now

The steps I have followed till now:

- Written this code

  ```
  spark = SparkSession(SparkContext())
  spark.conf.set(
      "fs.azure.account.key.%s.blob.core.windows.net" % AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
      AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY
  )
  spark.conf.set(
      "fs.wasbs.impl",
      "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem"
  )

  container_path = "wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net" % (
      AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME, AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
  )
  blob_folder = "%s/%s" % (container_path, AZURE_BLOB_NAME)
  df = spark.read.format("text").load(blob_folder)
  print(df.count())
  ```

  - Set public access and anonymous access to my Azure container.
  - Added two jars `hadoop-azure-2.7.3.jar` and `azure-storage-2.2.0.jar` to the path.

### Problem

But now I am stuck with this error: `Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Incorrect Blob type, please use the correct Blob type to access a blob on the server. Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual UNSPECIFIED.`.
I have not been able to find anything which talks about / resolves this issue. The closest I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37763472/3061686) which does not work / is outdated.

### EDIT

I found that the `azure-storage-2.2.0.jar` did not support `APPEND_BLOB`. I upgraded to `azure-storage-4.0.0.jar` and it changed the error from `Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual UNSPECIFIED.` to `Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual APPEND_BLOB.`. Does anyone know how to pass the correct type to expect?

Can someone please help me with resolving this.

I have minimal expertise in working with Azure but I don't think it should be this difficult to read and create a Spark dataframe from it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: This is how I managed to get it working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600404/220986

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read an append blob, which are not supported by WASB.

I think you should try using abfss, which does support it.
However I don't know how hard it might be to use in a custom Spark environment.

For exemple, here is how we do it in a Databricks Notebook with PySpark :

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>")
```

Hope this can help, your post is quite old but I really struggled with the same issue before using abfss... so hope it would help others.